# Default degree of parallelism in oracle hints

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance, optimizer-hints

I have used default degree of parallelism in order to gain performance tuning and I got the  best results too. but I doubt it will impact when some other job access the same table at same time.

sample code below.

```
select /*+ FULL(customer) PARALLEL(customer, default) */ customer_name  from customer;
```

The number of servers available is 8 . How this default degree of parallelism works? will it affect if some other job running query on same table at same time? Before moving this query to production , I would like to know whether this will impact ? Thanks!

Comment: See [How Parallel Execution Works](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel002.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#BABHFDDH):

**PARALLEL (DEFAULT):**

> The optimizer calculates a degree of parallelism equal to the number
>   of CPUs available on all participating instances times the value of
>   the PARALLEL_THREADS_PER_CPU initialization parameter.

The **[maximum degree of parallelism](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/initparams176.htm)** is limited by the number of **CPUs** in the system. The formula used to calculate the limit is :

`PARALLEL_THREADS_PER_CPU * CPU_COUNT * the number of instances available`

by default, all the opened instances on the cluster but can be constrained using `PARALLEL_INSTANCE_GROUP` or service specification. This is the default.